# Modifying remote System ODBC DSNs on win7, both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Tags: powershell, odbc, registry, dsn

I am trying to update DSNs on multiple different user boxes, which should be running Windows 7 x64.  People have sometimes created their own DSNs (maybe System, maybe User), and other places where admins have.  I want to replace the servername when it's a particular value, with a CNAME for that box.

I read this article, which seemed a good start: http://www.sqldataplatform.com/Blog/Post/9/Modifying-ODBC-Settings-with-WMI-and-PowerShell

However, when testing this on my box, I ran into a problem where I don't see the System DSNs I expect.

When I run the 64-bit "Data Sources (ODBC)" (C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe), which is the default when you go to Start->Administrative Tools->Data Sources, then I see the data source I created.  However, this doesn't work:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\"
```

Instead, I get a System DSN that I created in the 32-bit version of Data Sources (ODBC), aka "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe"

Oddly, if I run this, I get the exact same 32-bit DSN, where I'd expect to get the 32-bit and the 64-bit, even though I see them in different nodes when I open my registry.

```
Get-ChildItem -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" 
Get-ChildItem -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\"
```

So, any idea how I go about getting the other DSN? Thanks.

Comment: I think you're mixed up about which is the 32-bit version.  System32 is 64-bit, SysWow64 is 32-bit.

Comment: Okay, good to know.  I'll update.  Same problem applies, though - why can I see one, but not the other, and how can I see both?

Comment: To see the 32-bit one, you need to run C:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.  To see the 64-bit one, just run odbcad32.exe (from System32).

Comment: Right - running them ODBC app, I can see them.  Running regedit I see both keys.  But I can't grab both using powershell.

Comment: If you're running a 32-bit powershell session, you will only see the 32-bit one.  If you're running a 64-bit session, you can see both.

Comment: AHA!  Many thanks.  Didn't even think of there being a 32 & 64 bit version.

Comment: @MikeShepard if you want to post that as the answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the 32-bit one, you need to run C:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. To see the 64-bit one, just run odbcad32.exe (from System32).

If you're running a 32-bit powershell session, you will only see the 32-bit one. If you're running a 64-bit session, you can see both.